# Task.ContinueWith and TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to use `Task.ContinueWith` with `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` to execute a continuation task, e.g.

```
Task outerTask = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Outer"));
Task innerTask = outerTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine("Inner");
    }, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
outerTask.Start();
outerTask.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Outer done");
```

The output from this code is

```
Outer
Outer done
Inner
```

but what I expected/try to achieve is

```
Outer
Inner
Outer done
```

Is it possible to use `AttachedToParent` to block an outer task completion, or is `AttachedToParent` only effective for nested tasks?

Edit:

What I'm trying to achieve is a that I want to run a continuation task when `outerTask` is completed successfully. I want `outerTask` to propagate exceptions from `innerTask` to the caller, without having to deal with `innerTask`. If `outerTask` fails, it should just throw the exception right away (on `outerTask.Wait()` without calling `innerTask`).

Comment: innerTask is no inner task, but a task that's ran after outerTask completed. That's the point of "ContinueWith".

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow: So `AttachedToParent` is simply ignored by `ContinueWith`?

Comment: In this case it is ignored. When you create your task within another task, then you have an "inner" task where attached to parent matters.

Comment: Fyi: You don't need to wait with starting the task until you have hooked up continuations. You can start it right away. This, btw, is the reason continuations are no child tasks: You can hook them up any time later, so you can *never* say with confidence that all continuations have completed. New ones might come at any time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no parent-child tasks in your code.
You might want to check what is the inner or child task which can be of two types:

- [detached child task or nested task](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NestedTasks.aspx), i.e. parallel task created withing the delegate of another task without a connection to to the task-creator
- [attached child task or simply child task](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ChildTasks.aspx), in which case If a child task throws an exception that is otherwise unhandled, it is captured by the parent and rethrown

  **Update**

  > "Is it possible to use AttachedToParent to block an outer task
  >   completion..."
  >
  > "I want to run a continuation task when outerTask is
  >     completed successfully"

  CiCiting from the last:

  - "A parent task will not finish executing until all of its child tasks have completed, either normally or with exceptions. The parent essentially performs a Wait command for all of its children
  - If a child task throws an exception that is otherwise unhandled, it is captured by the parent and rethrown. It is possible for many child tasks to throw an exception. All will be combined with any unhandled exception thrown by the parent directly in a single AggregateException."

For your case, in which there are no parent-child tasks, read <s>[Handling Exceptions with Continuations](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ContinuationTasks_3.aspx):</s>

> "It is important to understand that there is no relationship between
>   antecedents and continuations, except for that which controls
>   scheduling. Specifically, exceptions thrown by a task are not
>   propagated to its linked continuation tasks. This means that you
>   should check for exceptions in all of the tasks that you run. The
>   simplest solution is to wait for all of the tasks that may error to
>   complete and surround the Wait method with a Try / Catch block"

There are also the code examples of catching-propagating exceptions in the provided by links articles

**Update:**

> Edit:
>
> What I'm trying to achieve is a that I want to run a continuation task
>   when outerTask is completed successfully. I want outerTask to
>   propagate exceptions from innerTask to the caller, without having to
>   deal with innerTask. If outerTask fails, it should just throw the
>   exception right away (on outerTask.Wait() without calling innerTask).

Probably, you have already seen the code example from MSDN article [Task.ContinueWith Method (Func, CancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions, TaskScheduler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784422%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which illustrates how to prevent/follow continuation task if antecedent fails/succedes (or vice versa, 4 combinations). But this is not parent-child, but antecedent-continuation tasks, so there is no containment or linking for exception propagation in either direction.

In case of child-parent tasks, it is impossible to prevent child tasks after they have been already launched and only after that a parent failed (or obviously cancel a parent from child).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, change the line

```
outerTask.Wait();
```

to

```
innerTask.Wait();
```

as soon as outertask completes, execution passes the Wait and writes 'Outer done' while the inner task is on Thread.Sleep.

Comment: The point here is that he's trying to have the child task itself extend the time that the parent time takes to consider itself "done", so that he could, for example, have a method that accepts a `Task`, add continuations, and have that make the passed in task take longer.  Other sections of code wouldn't know of the child at all.

Comment: +1 the @Steve's answer correctly answers to "but what I expected/try to achieve is Outer-> 
Inner->Outer done" output order. It is a guessing game whether the OP's trying to achieve WHAT or HOW

Answer (score -1):

The act of adding a continuation to a task will never change when the first task is considered "completed".  There is no way to force the parent to not be marked as "completed" until all (or even one particular) continuation is run.